# Sending @RequestBody from node js to Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, spring-rest

After spending more than half a day still not able to get down to whats wrong with the following:

Trying to send form data from NodeJSto Spring Rest API.

Node JS:

```
var inputData = { base : req.body.base, test : req.body.test }

var queryParams = {
          host: '127.0.0.1',
          port: 8080,
          path: '/start',
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
          body: inputData //Used JSON.stringify(inputData) - didn't work
        };
```

Using http module to send request:

```
var req = http.request(queryParams, function(res) {
        //do something with response
    });
    req.end();
```

Spring Rest:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String startApp(@RequestBody String body) {
        System.out.println(body);

        return "{\"msg\":\"Success\"}";
    }
```

Using postman I am able to see the same inputData going through the Rest. But when sent from NodeJS, all I see is

```
    { 
      timestamp: 1506987022646,
      status: 400,
      error: 'Bad Request',
      exception: 'org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException',
      message: 'Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String ApplicationController.startApp(java.lang.String)',
      path: '/start' 
    }
```

Using spring-boot-starter parent in the maven.

Am I missing anything here? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you put request body in `queryParams` will work.
You can try using `req.write()` to write data to request body as follows:

```
...  
req.write(inputData);  
req.end();
...
```